# Conditionally Applying class with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I've got a Button component that I'd like to assign an active class to if the state is 'true'.

```
<Button 
    onClick={this.preferenceHandler.bind(this, "straight")}  
    className={"col-sm-12 text-center " + (this.state.straight ? "active") }
    viewStyle=  "primary"
>
    <h4>Straight</h4>
    <i className="icon icon-ok-6"></i>
</Button>
```

Comment: You are missing `:` at conditional operator. That is,  if `this.state.straight` is `false`, what should occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the false expression in there:

```
className={"col-sm-12 text-center " + (this.state.straight ? "active" : "") }
```

Comment: Ahhh that's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To work with conditional classes is better if you use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#usage-with-reactjs)

```
var btnClass = classNames({
  'col-sm-12': true,
  'text-center': true,
  'active': this.state.straight
});
<Button 
    onClick={this.preferenceHandler.bind(this, "straight")}  
    className={btnClass}
    viewStyle="primary"
>
    <h4>Straight</h4>
    <i className="icon icon-ok-6"></i>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar with @rossipedia, but with ES6 template string

```js
className={`col-sm-12 text-center ${this.state.straight ? 'active' : ''}`}
```